# RGui: How can I show multiple charts produced by lineChart (module quantmod)?

Tags: r, quantmod

I'd like to open a window containing 6 charts or (even better) open 6 windows with 1 chart each. The chart is produced as follows:

```
#symbol 1
  symbol <- "SPY"
  data <- getSymbols(symbol , "yahoo", auto.assign=FALSE) 
  data <- adjustOHLC(data, use.Adjusted=TRUE)
  label <- symbol
  lineChart(data ,theme='white', name=label, subset = timeframe, TA="addRSI();addSMA(200);addSMA(20);addBBands(sd = 2)") 

#symbol 2
  symbol <- "DIA"
  data <- getSymbols(symbol , "yahoo", auto.assign=FALSE) 
  data <- adjustOHLC(data, use.Adjusted=TRUE)
  label <- symbol
  lineChart(data ,theme='white', name=label, subset = timeframe, TA="addRSI();addSMA(200);addSMA(20);addBBands(sd = 2)")
```

etc.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you're looking for `X11()`

Comment: Once you set the parameter `layout = NULL`, `lineChart` will no longer override your plot layout. That means you can adjust the layout, e.g. by setting `par(mfrow = c(3, 2))`. However, it will take some work to get a *nice* custom layout.